# Any way to generate javascript or pseudo code for a Data Flow?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-loops, code-generation, control-flow

I have a web form where users answer questions via dropdowns, and I wish to make other questions available based on their responses.

e.g. if your business has a premises then ask about opening hours. If they don't, show the regions they operate in.

**With each question I add to the process, the more complex the code becomes**. A lot of if/then functions that don't always have mutually exclusive answers.

Whilst each user may only have to answer 5-10 questions, the number of possible questions can be **100+**.

Is there a simple way to generate either Javascript/PHP or at the very least pseudo code which lets you plot a path through all the available answers and it generates the relevant nested if/then statements for you?

Example: [Akinator](http://uk.akinator.com/) guesses TV characters based on previous answers.

In anticipation of certain responses, of course the page doesn't **have** to be coded so that all questions are answered on one page, but I want to know if it's at least possible.

Thanks in advance. I hope you all enjoy WWDC ;)

Comment: `Is there a simple way to generate either Javascript/PHP or at the very least pseudo code`  I will tell you right off that this may be laughed off as being overly simplistic but your best bet would be -> A pencil and a couple of white sheets of paper. Write down what the application should do, and _then worry_ about how it will do this. (the implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a json object on the page that contains all of the rules and on each element have an id/attribute that corresponds to the json object. Then on change you check the json object for a "trigger" node that corresponds to the "change" element's attribute and then find all the elements that should be hidden/shown based upon that value. Note this code is really rough and not an exact answer but enough of an idea to get you started.

```
<select id='q1' onchange='handleHideShow(this)'></select>
<select id='q2' onchange='handleHideShow(this)'></select>

function handleHideShow(el)
{
    var elValue = el.value;
    if(hsObj[el.id])
    {
       var rules = hsObj[el.id].rules;
       for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++)
       {
           var rRule = rules[r];
           for(var t in rRule) 
           { 
               var showEl = document.getElementById(rRule[t]);
               if(showEl)
               {
                    var hideVal = "";
                    if(elValue != t)
                    {
                        hideVal = 'none';
                    }
                    showEl.styles.display = hideVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }               
}
var hsObj = [
   "q1":{"Yes":"q2"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of generating a lot of code, I'd think in terms of *avoiding* a lot of code.

If you've got a list of all possible questions, and you know which ones are the "start" questions, then what you need to know for each of them is:

- the question (text)
- the "name" of the question; in other words, some key for bookkeeping as you accumulate answers
- possible answers ("yes"/"no" or a list of options)
- for each possible answer, the identity of the next question to ask

With that, you just need one piece of code that knows how to present a question and act on the answer.  It should accumulate the answers in a list, as it gets them from the user. You can even provide a navigation scheme to allow users to go backwards.